# RxJava Observable.doOnUnsubscribe() vs Subscriber.add()

Tags: rx-java

I sometimes have to do some clean up tasks in my Observables (e.g. closing open files) and I was wondering what is the best approach.
So far I've seen two but I struggle to understand what's their difference: could you explain the differences and if there are any better ways to achieve this?

1)

```
    // MyObject will take care of calling onNext(), onError() and onCompleted()
    // on the subscriber.
    final MyObject o = new MyObject();

    Observable obs = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
            try {
                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {

                    o.setSubscriber(subscriber);

                    // This will tell MyObject to start allocating resources and do its job.
                    o.start();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    }).doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            // This will tell MyObject to finish its job and deallocate any resources.
            o.stop();
        }
    });
```

2)

```
    Observable obs = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
            try {
                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {

                    // MyObject will take care of calling onNext(), onError() and onCompleted()
                    // on the subscriber.
                    final MyObject o = new MyObject(subscriber);

                    subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(new Action0() {
                        @Override
                        public void call() {
                            // This will tell MyObject to finish its job and deallocate any resources.
                            o.stop();
                        }
                    }));

                    // This will tell MyObject to start allocating resources and do its job.
                    o.start();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have used `doOnSubscribe` in the example 1. It should be `doOnUnsubscribe` as mentioned in the question title.

Comment: @PraveerGupta thanks I fixed the typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your original question, both `doOnUnSubscribe` and adding a `Subscription` to the `Subscriber` is same. In fact, when you call `doOnUnSubscribe` it just adds your `Action` as a `Subscription` to your `Subscriber`. So, `doOnUnSubscribe` uses your second example in background.

`doOnUnSubscribe` Code  :

```
public class OperatorDoOnUnsubscribe<T> implements Operator<T, T> {
  private final Action0 unsubscribe;

/**
 * Constructs an instance of the operator with the callback that gets invoked when the modified Observable is unsubscribed
 * @param unsubscribe The action that gets invoked when the modified {@link rx.Observable} is unsubscribed
 */
public OperatorDoOnUnsubscribe(Action0 unsubscribe) {
    this.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;
}

@Override
public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super T> child) {
    child.add(Subscriptions.create(unsubscribe));

    // Pass through since this operator is for notification only, there is
    // no change to the stream whatsoever.
    return Subscribers.wrap(child);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The decision of which of the two solutions, that you have mentioned, to use ***depends upon whether the resource, that you are trying to use/close/dispose, is meant to be shared between multiple subscriptions***.

1. Use **subscriber.add(...)** when the resource is used to generate the events. In such a scenario you will NOT want to share the resource.

   - This is the case in your example of `MyObject`. This has the benefit that the resource will not be exposed outside the `Observable.create()` method and thus make the resource free from accidental side-effects.
2. Use **doOnUnsubscribe** when you have to share something across multiple subscriptions.

   - As an example, if you want to have a counter of how many times the Observable was used, you can have a shared counter and keep on incrementing in the `doOnUnsubscribe` or `doOnSubscribe`.
   - Another example can be if you want to have a counter of how many connections are currently open to the resource, you can use increment and decrement combination in `doOnSubscribe` and `doOnUnsubscribe` correspondingly to achieve that.

Also in your example, instead of creating the `MyObject` abstraction, which is managing opening and closing of resources and generating events, you can replace it with the `Observable.using()` method to achieve the same. It takes in three arguments:

- `resourceFactory`, which will open the resource,
- `observableFactory`, which will generate events  and
- `disposeAction`, which will close the resource

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of using Observable.create if you are not putting any values downstream with subscriber.onNext?

The first one ist a huge no-no, because you are doing side effects to a object which has been closed over. What would happen if you woud subscribe to the created observable from two different threads at the same time?

The second one looks better, because you add subscriber.add, which will invoke o.stop() if a subscription has been disposed. The only thing which is missing is the invokation of onNext, that the value traveles downstream.

There is a operator for create Observables from resources, which is called "using". Please have a look at http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#using(rx.functions.Func0,%20rx.functions.Func1,%20rx.functions.Action1)

Comment: Regarding your first sentence: MyObject will call onNext/onCompleted/onError on the subscriber set with setSubscriber() right after having been started with start().

Regarding your second sentence: I don't get it, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Which version of RxJava are you using? I want to reconstruct your example. Of what type is MyObject?

Comment: Using rxJava 1.2.0

Comment: MyObject is just an example type, it means "object encapsulating some custom logic"

Comment: Please have a look at the following example: https://gist.github.com/SergejIsbrecht/e4bed81320a1738834dedb5da67a426d

Comment: Your second solution is way better than the first one, because it does not depend on shared/ mutable state. Lets have a look at the first one. The first one closes over a shared state. If you subscribe to obs in the first example two times on different threads, you will setSubscriber two times. Is it thread-safe? Will the first one be overriden by the second subscriber? As a matter of fact, the doOnSub method will be called before you produce any values. You will first call stop, then start from multiple subs.

Comment: I think I might have conveyed the wrong meaning with my 1st example. Example 1 was actually written after example 2 and to do so I had to pull `o` out of the Observable.create() otherwise I couldn't call `close()` on it during `doOnUnsubscribe()` and doing so I've unintendedly created shared state. The focus of the question was to understand how the resulting observables from the 2 examples differed and I think @bharath-mg answer's nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

First up don't use `Observable.create(OnSubscribe)` if you can help it because you can easily break stuff (like backpressure or Observable contract related things). You should use one of the many static factory methods.

That aside instead of addressing your question directly, I'd recommend `Observable.using` which is designed explicitly to release resources on termination or unsubscription.

For example:

```
Observable<byte[]> bytes = 
  Observable.using(
    () -> new FileInputStream(file), //resource factory
    is -> Bytes.from(is), // observable factory
    is -> is.close() // close action
  );
```

The above example misses some try-catches (for example around `is.close()`) that won't appear if you use RxJava 2.

Attempting to flesh out your case:

```
Observable.using(
  () -> new MyObject(), //resource factory
  myObject -> makeObservable(myObject), // observable factory
  myObject -> myObject.stop() // close action
);
```

Comment: I've tried your approach though it doesn't work out for me because the logic that calls onError/onNext/onCompleted is inside `MyObject` (which in your case is represented by the `FileInputStream`) .
I think I can't escape `Observable.create(OnSubscribe)` this time.

Comment: Your  Observable creation can be independent of the closing aspect. I've added more detail to my answer. Ultimately you should explore not using `Observable.create` perhaps in another StackOverflow question.